# What is a good pattern for combined caching and reinitialization?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, methods, lazy-initialization

I have a situation where I have three requirements:

1. **Lazy initialization** - don't create the collection until asked for it
2. **Caching** - keep the collection in memory on the object
3. **Reinitialization** - be able to reinitialize the collection when desired, instead of simply getting the existing results.

This is simply an optimization inside a single class - it is not loading anything from a database and ideally I'd like just a good method design pattern for this, not a multiple-class design.

Usually for lazy initialization I'd have this:

```
Collection getCollection() {
    if (collection != null) {
         // generate and set collection
    }
    return collection;
}
```

But now I'm having trouble deciding on the best way to provide for reinitialization of a fresh collection and getting that collection.  A `fresh` boolean parameter would work, but adding a parameter to a getter doesn't seem to feel right (maybe that's the Java in me talking — I could be convinced).

Comment: Warning--this isn't thread-safe!

Comment: @Loren I suppose that sort of depends on the generate code.  I could have specified that this object will only exist within the scope of one thread, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're limiting yourself to a single method call then I can't honestly imagine a parameterless solution that distinguishes between retrieving the cached value and a reinitialized value.

Every cache I've seen uses one of the following patterns:

- An `Invalidate` or `Expire` method that flags the value for reinitialization on the next lookup;
- A boolean or enumeration parameter, such as the one you've ruled out;
- A separate reinitialization method, i.e. `getNewCollection`.

I do think it must be the Java in you talking, because in other languages I'm very much accustomed to passing parameters in cache lookups - in some cases one of the parameters may even be an anonymous method or function pointer telling the cache how to get the value.

When designing a cache based on deferred initialization, you'll almost certainly also want to have method overloads that take parameters for priority and/or expiration, since there's no longer any `Put` or `Store` method to hold them.  So, I think the notion of a parameterless lazy-loaded lookup method *with* optional refresh is pretty much out the window.

If you're uncomfortable with it being a getter, then just give it a different name like `Load` or `Lookup`.

P.S. I realize you may not actually be designing a cache here, but the principles still apply; you don't want to have something that acts like a cache internally but doesn't provide cache semantics.  That would just lead to headaches.

Comment: Clarified question: not entirely opposed to parameters, also not completely attached to the idea of a combined method call. (+1, good summary of the options)

Answer (score 1):

I would add an extra method instead of passing a boolean parameter:

```
Collection getFreshCollection()
{
   collection = null;

   return getCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be worth it in this case, but you could have a little class that hangs onto the collection and has two (public) methods: one for getting the cached value, and one for getting an updated/recomputed value.  Both methods would probably have to have the lazy initialization code in them, unless you know for sure which one will get called first.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP).  Caching is a fairly common use of AOP, and java has a pretty nice AOP tool called AspectJ.

It will help you keep your caching concerns separate from the entity or persistence concerns.